# Forgot Firebase account | Firebase Console | Can ı move an app to another project in a different firebase account?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, android-push-notification

I am having an a Android App linked with a firebase console, but I forgot the user email&Password. As I am using Android Push notifications in that app, I need to update the Firebase credentials in App Settings before June 20. Since I don't remember the account details, can someone suggest any alternative.?

Can I create the same app in another Firebase account without deleting the old one.?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new Firebase account for your Android app without deleting the old one. To do this, you need to follow these steps:

1. Create a new Firebase project and add the Firebase Authentication
   library to your app's Gradle file.
2. Enable the Email/Password sign-in method in the Firebase console.
3. In your app, use the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method to
   create a new user account with the new email address and password.

By following these steps, you can create a new Firebase account for your Android app without deleting the old one.